# Zend Framework 2: Composing web page of several parts

Tags: php, templates, zend-framework2

I need to compose a web page of several view templates (the view template rendering page content and a view template rendering sidebar). In my layout.phtml, I have two variable placeholders: $content and $sidebar:

```
......
<?php echo $this->sidebar; ?>
......
<?php echo $this->content; ?>
......
```

In my controller's action, I pass the data to these view templates through the ViewModels chained in a tree:

```
public function indexAction() {

 // Preparing my data
 // $form = ...
 // $menuItems = 
 // $activeItem =       

 // Create sidebar view model
 $sidebarViewModel = new ViewModel(array('menuItems'=>$menuItems, 'activeItem'=>$activeItem));
 // Add it as a child to layout view model
 $this->layout()->addChild($sidebarViewModel, 'sidebar');

 // Page content view model
 $viewModel = new ViewModel(array('form'=>$form));
 return $viewModel;     
}
```

But, because I have the sidebar on every page, I will have to copy and paste this code for every action of every controller. Is there any recommended way of reusing the code that populates the ViewModel for sidebar?

Comment: I guess this fits: [widgetized content in zf2](http://www.michaelgallego.fr/blog/2012/10/06/how-to-replace-the-action-helper-in-zf-2-and-make-great-widgetized-content/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to achieve this with a controller plugin.

Assuming you have wired it up with appropriate config, and you're in the Application module.

In `module/Application/src/Application/Controller/Plugin/AddSidebar.php`:

```
namespace Application\Controller\Plugin;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\AbstractPlugin;

class addSidebar extends AbstractPlugin {

    public function __invoke($menu, $active) {

        // create new view model
        $sidebarVM = new ViewModel(array(
            'menuItems'  => $menu,
            'activeItem' => $active
        ));

        // add it to the layout
        $this->getController()->layout()->addChild($sidebarVM, 'sidebar');

    }

}
```

Then in each of your controllers:

```
$this->addSidebar($menuItems, $activeItem);
```

Another (probably better) option would be to hook into the render `MvcEvent` and add the sidebar there. You'd have to work out how to generate `$menuItems` and `$activeItem` in that context however.

Comment: many thanks for the answer , we will appreciate if you explain this more in details.

Comment: Which part of the setup would you like more details on?

Comment: I found that this topic is well explained in the [Using Zend Framework 2](https://leanpub.com/using-zend-framework-2) book. Very easy for beginners.